# Cannot Install Anything Using easy_install.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I was trying to install `beautifulsoup4` and `pyreadline` using easy install in Python 2.7 in Windows 7 (64 bit). I am getting "timed out -- some packages may not be found" error. I tried many solutions, one of them was using pip instead of easy_install so, I tried to install "pip". But I keep on getting same kind of error.

Any help would be great. I can install "`pyreadline`" using windows binary but want to know the solution.

I don't know why do they call this "easy" install.

Here is the screenshot of error (don't have 10 rep).
http://i62.tinypic.com/24wrbx3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an old version of pip which tries to download packages from the wrong location. 
Please [install a newer version of pip.](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html)

You can verify if you have the latest version with:

```
pip --version
```

Comment: I am using easy_install.exe to install pip but its not working

Comment: follow the instructions in the link! There is a reason I put it. Easy install is probably also looking in the wrong place.

Comment: **I followed what the link said.** and the error was

`Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\<myusername>\pip\pip.log`

Comment: Ok, it seems that the main repository is experiencing some problem. Wait a couple of hours, and then see.